# asp.net handler like mvc routing without mvc?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, global-asax

I used to build my web apps in asp.net in such there is only one page witch is default.aspx

```
http://localhost/mywebapp1/?q=blog/posts/get/42
```

I do parse 'q' by myself and do all processing. I don't really need to all MVC staff. I just want to remove "?q="

any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use ASP.NET Routing outside of ASP.NET MVC. [This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd347546.aspx) MSDN article explains how.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using IIS 7 (Windows 2008 / Vista or higher) you could use the IIS URL Rewrite module from http://www.iis.net/download/URLRewrite

You define the rules either in web.config or through the IIS front end.

For example I use the following for friendly URLS to shop items on my site.

It makes mysite.com/shop/package-one to to mysite.com/shop/default.aspx?package=package-one

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="ShopPackages" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^shop/(.*)"/>
      <conditions>
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true"/>
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="/shop/default.aspx?package={R:1}" appendQueryString="false"/>
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```